# Best approach for converting list of nested dictionaries to a single dictionary with aggregate functions

Tags: python, pandas, hash-map

I've looked through a lot of solutions on this topic, but I have been unable to adapt my case to a performant one. Suppose I have a list of dictionaries stored as:

```
db_data = [
  {
    "start_time": "2020-04-20T17:55:54.000-00:00",
    "results": {
      "key_1": ["a","b","c","d"],
      "key_2": ["a","b","c","d"],
      "key_3": ["a","b","c","d"]
    }
  },
  {
    "start_time": "2020-04-20T18:32:27.000-00:00",
    "results": {
      "key_1": ["a","b","c","d"],
      "key_2": ["a","b","e","f"],
      "key_3": ["a","e","f","g"]
    }
  },
  {
    "start_time": "2020-04-21T17:55:54.000-00:00",
    "results": {
      "key_1": ["a","b","c"],
      "key_2": ["a"],
      "key_3": ["a","b","c","d"]
    }
  },
  {
    "start_time": "2020-04-21T18:32:27.000-00:00",
    "results": {
      "key_1": ["a","b","c"],
      "key_2": ["b"],
      "key_3": ["a"]
    }
  }
]
```

I am trying to get a data aggregation from the list output as a dictionary, with the key values of the results object as the keys of the output, and the size of the set of unique values for each date for each key.

I am attempting to aggregate the data by date value, and outputting the count of unique values for each key for each day.

Expected output is something like:

```
{
  "key_1": {
    "2020-04-20": 4,
    "2020-04-21": 3
  },
  "key_2": {
    "2020-04-20": 6,
    "2020-04-21": 2
  },
  "key_3": {
    "2020-04-20": 7,
    "2020-04-21": 4
  }
}
```

What I have tried so far is using `defaultdict` and loops to aggregate the data. This takes a very long time unfortunately:

```
from datetime import datetime
from collections import defaultdict

grouped_data = defaultdict(dict)

for item in db_data:
  group = item['start_time'].strftime('%-b %-d, %Y')
  for k, v in item['results'].items():
    if group not in grouped_data[k].keys():
      grouped_data[k][group] = []
    grouped_data[k][group] = v + grouped_data[k][group]
for k, v in grouped_data.items():
  grouped_data[k] = {x:len(set(y)) for x, y in v.items()}

print(grouped_data)
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated. I have read that `pandas` might help here, but I am not quite sure how to adapt this use case.

Comment: How many entries, approximately, are in your input data?

Comment: there are about 500 now, but that will continue to grow pretty steadily

Comment: And how slow is "too slow"? How long does this take to execute currently? And what is the prior system that is generating these data?

Comment: too slow is that those 500 records took ~50 seconds to process

Comment: Can you guarantee that the inner values are one character as you've shown?

Comment: No, they aren't one character, they are always multiple characters, I was merely using that as a an example

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import date, datetime
from typing import DefaultDict, Set, List, Dict


DefaultSet = DefaultDict[date, Set[str]]


def default_set() -> DefaultSet:
    return defaultdict(set)


aggregated: DefaultDict[str, DefaultSet] = defaultdict(default_set)

for entry in db_data:
    start_date: date = datetime.fromisoformat(entry['start_time']).date()
    result: Dict[str, List[str]] = entry['results']
    for k, v in result.items():
        aggregated[k][start_date].update(v)

grouped_data: Dict[str, Dict[date, int]] = {
    k: {gk: len(gv) for gk, gv in group.items()}
    for k, group in aggregated.items()
}
```

Notes:

- I do not know if this is faster, but it's certainly simpler
- If you're able, maintain the output with actual `date` keys
- Your data are better-modeled by a `defaultdict` of `defaultdict`s of `set`s.
- I used a bunch of type hints to make sure that I'm doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I tested it out and it was much better than mine, but still a bit slow. This is what I finally went with though from another forum post:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from functools import partial
>>>
>>> flat_list = ((key, db_item['start_time'][:10], results)
...               for db_item in db_data
...               for key, results in db_item['results'].items())
>>> 
>>> d = defaultdict(partial(defaultdict, set))
>>> 
>>> for key, date, li in flat_list:
...     d[key][date].update(li)
```

It works really well! It improved processing time from 50 seconds to 2 seconds

Comment: This does not look complete, though. After the `update` step there is still a `len` required somewhere.

Comment: That's true, though in the actual display of this data (I am using plotly), I can iterate the output of the above to build the plotly data and call len(d[key][date]) to get the values at runtime.